# What is a good open source alternative to Kannel for SMS gateway?

Tags: mobile, sms, gateway, wap, kannel

I need to setup an open source SMS gateway to send messages using my mobile phone via USB cable. I tried [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) but its lack of GUI frustrated the user who is intended to admin it (not an advanced user).

Comment: Hello,

Kannel is the best open source version have seen so far , that are so many other implementation but i can not vouch for them.

Kannel Configuration and installation is very easy ... if you can specify the challenges the Admin user has we might be able to help

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to use local GSM modem (or just mobile phone) you can use the following server side alternatives:

- http://wammu.eu/gammu/ - Gammu (fork of Gnokii)
- http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/ - SMS Server Tools
- https://metacpan.org/pod/GSM::SMS - GSM::SMS (includes messaging daemon)

For GUI you can use the following software:

- http://playsms.org/ - PlaySMS (works with Kannel, Gammu)
- http://kalkun.sourceforge.net/ - Kalkun (works with Gammu)
- http://wammu.eu/wammu/ - Wammu (GUI to Gammu SMSD)

Note: Kannel is excellent platform for large scale SMS platforms but it requires certain level of understanding underlying technologies and integration layer.

Comment: Great answer! Are there other gateways that rival Kannel(performance,reliability) for a user not interesed in UI?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel try Jasmin sms gateway

Comment: Is there anything that supports MMS too? the Mbuni project is dead and I'm looking for an alternative

Answer (score 7):

Mobicents SMSC Gateway is another open source option with broad commercial deployment. It complements a suite of open source telco middleware Mobicents projects such as USSD Gateway, SS7 stack, Diameter charging server, SIP Servlets and so on.

The Mobicents SMSC Gateway is specifically designed to integrate with operator core networks over SS7 E1/T1 or SIGTRAN in addition to SMPP connectivity over IP.

http://code.google.com/p/smscgateway/

http://www.telestax.com/opensource/

Comment: I actually think he means something different by SMS Gateway - as Kannel and Mobicents does not quite fall into the same category nor do they provide the same functionality. But an up-vote since this is answering the question he asked as opposed to the question he meant.

Comment: Thank you, Iwan. I believe you are correct. As far as I know, Kannel is focused on SMPP traffic routing, while Mobicents SMSC covers SMPP, SIP IM and legacy SS7 MAP interfaces. Please point out other key differences that I'm missing. Thank you.